# Mounting a TV above a fireplace with an unknown stone

Tags: mounting, stone

Just moving into a new place and I moved the TV in today. I took the old mount down and figured I would use it at the new place so I kept all of the screws. New house has a nice fireplace in the living room that I would love to place the TV over. I went to start trying to find a stud and found out the wall is solid stone. Previously I mounted only to drywall so I figured I might be in over my head. I figured I would mount the TV on another wall just to discover that all of the walls in the house are stone. Now I am really not sure what to do or even what to look up because I am not sure what kind of stone this is. Could anyone here help guide me in the right direction? How do I figure out what kind of stone the walls are? Also can I mount a TV to stone?

And before anyone says anything about how we should've been told before buying the house, it was inherited so a lot of the information discovered in the buying process was lost.

Comment: If it is really **stone** and not a stone veneer on top of something else, then you can drill holes and mount similar to mounting in concrete or brick. Post some pictures - that may help us figure it out.

Comment: I will post some tomorrow if I remember. But it is just a flat stone. It may be concrete I am not sure. When I said stone I just meant anything within that category. Its flat and painted over. Slightly textured but not enough to see in a picture. Just a rough texture when you feel it. But just looking at it it looks like a normal wall. How do I tell if its stone and not veneer?

Comment: The question is: what's behind the stone. You might be able to take a drill with a good bit and drill in a few (hopefully inconspicuous locations) and see what you find. It could be: thin stone (e.g., veneer) on top of drywall/studs, thin or thick stone on top of some sort of solid supporting structure (e..g, brick or concrete), or a stone wall supported by itself (just stone).

Comment: "just to discover that all of the walls in the house are stone"  I don't think all the walls of the house are stone.  I think the OP is unfamiliar with plastered walls.  Heavy plaster over lathe, and a stud finder may not give good readings.

Answer (score 1):

Mounting a TV above a fireplace is an overall bad thing to do.

1. Fireplaces get hot. Electronics do not like heat.
2. Above fireplace places TV at a less than optimum viewing angle. TVs are designed for best image looking mostly straight on at eye level whilst sitting on a typical couch.
3. Getting connection power cords and signal cables up around the side of the fireplace and to the area of the bracket is totally hampered by the firebox and chimney that is inside the wall. Normal in wall hiding of cables is not possible and leads to an ugly installation.

Comment: The old fireplace was remodeled to just be electric with no heat (just shows some flames behind a screen). It was a real fireplace before as there is a chimney above it, but currently it just lights up and displays the flames. As for the viewing angle, I don't think it can be too bad because the previous tv was on the mantle, just not mounted. Issue is the legs for the TV seem to have gotten lost in the move.

Also, as I pointed out, I tried to mount on other walls only to discover that they are also stone. So moving the mount location doesn't solve the original issue.