# Help mounting tv above fireplace

Tags: fireplace, television, mount

I am trying to mount a TV above my gas fireplace. I have read about the issues with mounting TVs there, but I have a sealed gas fireplace and I use it less than once a year.

I found the studs using a magnetic stud finder, and then used finishing nails to poke little holes to find the edges of the stud. However, I am measuring around 3.25 inches from end to end, which is a bit confusing. The magnetic stud finder is marking approx the center of the 3.25 inches. I am thinking that they put in studs in with the longer side facing outwards, rather than it being a double stack of studs since I'm measuring more than 3 inches. So I am planning to put in the lag screws in the middle where the magnet is hitting, but wanted to hear what advice you all have for this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: It only needs to be on once to cause a fire.

Comment: What's the question? Please revise to ask something more specific. We're not a discussion forum. [Take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more.

Comment: The viewing angle is going to suck, but if you still want to do it you need to edit and add more information, like the weight of the TV plus the bracket. You also need to measure the thickness of the wood, sometimes the wood around a fireplace is thin, just to mount drywall on, with less weight bearing capacity than a stud.

Answer (score 4):

Studs above a fireplace are often placed flat instead of on edge against the brick/chimney. This is done so the wall can be thinner in that area. So I think you are you are right in saying you think the wide face of the stud is against the back side of the drywall.

I really encourage you to re-think the idea of placing a TV up high over a fire-place. This is a terrible place to put a TV for quite a number of reasons. If you search here you can find multiple answers I have given on this subject and why this is a bad idea. Here are some of those answers:

https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/189273/7367

https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/154218/7367

Answer (score 3):

## *Most important*

You need to look at the requirements of your TV mount.

If you're mounting into the 1.5" depth of a stud on the flat instead of the 3.5" depth of a stud on edge, your mounting bolts don't have as much wood to bite into and won't hold as much weight. If you have a big mount for a big TV, it may call for lag bolts longer than 1.5".

You can, of course, mount it with shorter bolts, it's your TV and your house, but if your bolts aren't long enough (as determined by the manufacturer) to support the weight of the mount and the TV, it may lead to a sudden, unplanned meeting of TV and floor.

---

### Additional concerns

#### Viewing Angle

When you mount the TV up high, you're going to be looking up at it. If you have enough recliner chairs for *everyone* likely to be watching at your big Superbowl party, that's probably not an issue, if not, somebody's going to have a sore neck from the uncomfortable angle. If you have a mount that tilts, you can, of course angle the TV down so you're mostly withing the viewing angle that the screen will look good at, but you're still looking up at it.

Additionally, if there are any lights above the TV, or even anywhere on the ceiling between the seating area and the screen, they'll be distracting at minimum and possibly causing glare/reflections on the screen.

#### Heat

The heat from the fireplace will not do the electronics in the TV any favors. Of course, some people seem to "upgrade" to larger TVs with more features on a somewhat regular basis, so you may be replacing the TV long before it's worn out, even with the accelerated wear caused by the additional heat. This may or may not be an issue for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I appreciate the comments about viewing angle, I actually got the mantelmount mm340 that you can lower the height of the TV.  I considered the double stud vs stud on its side issue, I ended up drilling a pilot hole for the lag bolt and found that the wood does not go past 2 inches deep, so seems like it is a 2x4 turned 90 degrees. The issue I figure with that is that the lag bolts are about 2.25 inches so I'm missing a little bite on those, but my TV is about 38 pounds vs the manufacturer's limit of 90 lbs.

Comment: @aereties it's your TV, so feel free to mount it as you wish! :) You indicated that the wood is only ~2" thick, what's behind it? Solid masonry? Hollow masonry? Air? Brick (red swarf coming out of the hole)? Concrete (white swarf coming out of the hole)? There are toggle bolts designed to hold large amounts of weight that will work for any of those situations, I'd suggest using the appropriate ones just to ensure the TV doesn't take a dive just before the big play.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on mounting it above the fireplace then i would recommend that you use a 3/4" board as a mounting plate to span at least three studs.

Bolt the board into the studs with lags **and** some [toggle anchor's](https://www.lowes.com/pd/TOGGLER-10-Pack-Assorted-Length-x-1-4-in-Dia-Toggle-Bolt-Drywall-Anchor-Screws-Included/3183831), these are long enough to go through 3-5/8-in thick wall, so they should be long enough to go all the way through the stud, drywall and board. But do a test hole first, make a mock up of stud, drywall and board, to  make sure you have the clearance to swing the toggle into place. Use a broad washer for the anchor bolt.

Make sure your TV mount lags go through the board and into the studs. Make sure the lags have threads all the way to the head so that the threads are both biting into the mounting board and the studs. ( *You may even be able to use the anchor's for the TV mount itself, which would be solid*. )